# Clean architecture in visual studio for Azure function apps

Tags: visual-studio, architecture, azure-functions, azure-pipelines, clean-architecture

I have a requirement of building few azure function app for a data transformation project. So there are few services (Which we need to make as separate function apps to apply scalability) consumes or shares common cosmos DB, event grid, service bus etc.

So for the design I was following [Jason Taylors Clean Architecture](https://jasontaylor.dev/clean-architecture-getting-started/)
[image]

So the structure is like this

```
Solution
|
---src (Directory)
     |
     --- Domain Layer (Project)
     --- Application Layer (Project)
     --- Infrastructure Layer (Project)
     --- functions
       |
       --- Function1 (project)
       --- Function2 (project)
       --- Function3 (project)
     --- Web Ui (Project)
```

So each of the functions project and UI is depending on the application layer.

But my concern is whenever a change in Domain layer happens we are required to deploy all the functions as well, isnt it?

Or is there is any best way to handle this scenario? Like no need to deploy the ui or functions when main layer changes?? I have heard some artefacts way.. But not clear that.

Comment: What, in your opinion, is the benefit of using this architecture in combination with azure functions? If you need to use azure functions then don't couple them tightly to your main app as they now share the same lifecycle.

Comment: The reason we thought about separate solution  is, if so when a small change we have to make the same change in other solutions as well.. Please suggest a better approach

Answer (score 1):

**Please check if my findings help to**:

I have gone through the [Jayson Taylor Clean Architecture Solution Template](https://jasontaylor.dev/clean-architecture-getting-started/) and few other GitHub articles.

- I believe that your approach is correct in implementation of Clean Architecture in your application because it becomes very easy to have many ways to start your application and if that application is capable of starting up with any type of presentation layer like API, Console or an Azure Function.

I have referred this [GitHub article1](https://github.com/cbcrouse/CleanArchitecture) and [GitHub article 2](https://github.com/swilkodev/CleanFunc50), where I understand that you can use Azure Functions in presentation layer for starting up the application.

- The above articles explained a bit about how to integrate Clean Architecture .NET Solution with Azure Functions to utilize its runtime which acts as entrance to the application.